# Selenium Python Class Names are the same

Tags: python, selenium, class, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to code a program that displays text from a website. the classes that the text is in have the same name. i have tried to do xpath, but I cant get that to work. i don't really know how to explain my question, sorry about that.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

(deleted code that doesn't affect this)
(I have a problem with the code below)
print('Assignment 1')
time.sleep(6)
assignment1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("calendar-title-text")
print(assignment1.text)
assignment2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("calendar-title-text"[1])
print(assignment2.text)

time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: class names are generally used for many items.  IDs should be unique.  If there is no ID, use href or text, or whatever is unique about that element.  If absolutely nothing is unique, you'd need to use a path e.g. //div/div[2]/a... (but avoid that as it tends to be pretty brittle)

Answer (score 0):

So, I think what you are asking is: "How can I select 1 element using xpath if I have multiple elements?"

And, to answer, I provided a photo to you for demonstration purposes.

Say, for example, we go to Google.com and we search "Hello World Python"

Link: [Hello World Python in Google.com](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk00PcSCl3USgIeza3HHsoYZybkpY7A%3A1605637820890&ei=vBa0X-3pNcaw5wL9obKwAw&q=Hello%20World%20Python&oq=Hello%20World%20Python&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICAAQsQMQyQMyAggAMgIIADICCC4yAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BAgAEEc6BwgAEMkDEEM6BQgAELEDOggIABCxAxCDAToECC4QQzoFCC4QsQM6CAgAEMkDEIsDOggILhCxAxCLAzoFCAAQiwM6BQguEIsDOggIABCxAxCLAzoLCC4QxwEQrwEQiwM6BQgAEMkDOgsILhCxAxDJAxCTAlCiCljIHWDpH2gAcAJ4AIABhgGIAecJkgEDOS40mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCLgBAsABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjtt87_mortAhVG2FkKHf2QDDYQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)

In this search, we are given a lot of results

[image: Hello World Python Search Results]

When you open your Google Chrome Developer Tools ( F12 ) and you navigate to the `Elements` tab and press `CTRL + F`, a search bar will display at the bottom of the page.

When we search through the `HTML` code, we have an `xpath` that gives us multiple results when we search for a class name.

```
//div[@id='search']//div[@id='rso']//div[@class='g']
```

This `xpath` returns us a `1 of 12` result. But, we want `1 of 1`. In order to accomplish this, we need to wrap our `xpath` in parenthesis (). This will help us in isolating only 1 of our elements.

```
(//div[@id='search']//div[@id='rso']//div[@class='g'])[1]
```

This `xpath` will result in `1 of 1`. This should allow you to be able to interact with the web element.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='search']//div[@id='rso']//div[@class='g'])[1]").click()
```

[image: Image of xpath examples with text]

If you wanted to interact with the text of an element, as an example, we can print out the highlighted text with the following command

```
xpath = "((//div[@id='search']//div[@id='rso']//div[@class='g'] )[1]//div[@data-hveid]//div)[7]//div"
element_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).text
print(f'My Text Is: {element_text}')
```

[image: Hello World Python Google.com Image Text Highlight]

[image: Xpath Sample for Text Display]